# Unexpected behavior of floating point numbers in C

Tags: c

I have a simple C snippet as follows:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main()    
{
    float a=0.3,b=0.5
    clrscr();

    if(a==0.3)
    {
        printf("equal");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("unequal");
    }

    if(b==0.5)
    {
        printf("equal");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("unequal");
    }

    getch();
}
```

shows output as: `unequal equal`.

I understand this because computer takes `0.3` as `1/3` and as `0.333...` is not equal to `0.33`, it shows output unequal, while in `0.5` is precise number so it gives output as `equal`.

But now if I take `float b=0.2` like this:

```
float b=0.2;
if(b==0.2)
{
    printf("equal");
}
else
{
    printf("unequal");
}
```

Then it also shows `unequal` as output! As `0.2` is  `1/5` - precise value, it should give output `equal`.

Can anyone tell me if anything is wrong here?

Comment: Read any basic text about floating-point numbers.

Comment: "I understand this because computer takes `0.3` as `1/3`": Why should it do so? "and as 0.333... is not equal to 0.33" Where does the 0.33 come from now?

Comment: @Deduplicator i searched on the web and found some results about truncation error.but AFAIK, 1/5 does not give any truncation error.

Comment: @krupalshah Convert 1/5 to decimal and you'll see that it indeed is truncated as well. But if you take .25, .125, .0625 etc, it is not truncated.

Comment: You should use `double` or cast literals to `float` if you absolutely need to make those comparisons with literals, as they are of type `double`. http://codepad.org/RfTDQ9XL

Comment: `short int x = 65537; if (x == 65537) printf("equal\n");`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplifying somewhat, floating point numbers are basically stored as a series of fractions of powers of 2. (1/2, 1/4, 1/8, 1/16, 1/32, 1/64, etc).   If your number can be represented as the sum of some number of those, you are lucky -- for most numbers (1/3, 1/5, etc) you get a pretty close approximation.  Comparing floating point numbers for exact equality is fraught with peril.

Comment: See also the previous question linked to by Deduplicator for a lot longer and more complete and complex answer.